# Async Restsharp getting data into datacontext

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net, restsharp

```
public class BerichtenOphalen
{
    public List<Bericht> berichten = new List<Bericht>();

    public List<Bericht> getBerichten(string email)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8080/ewm/resources");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("lode_vl@hotmail.com",     "123456");
        var request = new RestRequest("berichten/ontvanger/{id}", Method.GET);
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", email);
        List<Bericht> berichten = new List<Bericht>();
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("not null" + response.Content.ToString());
                this.berichten = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Bericht>>(response.Content);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\n" +berichten.Count);
            }   
        });
        return berichten;
    }
```

This class works, But i cant figure out how to return the List that is filled with objects.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    BerichtenOphalen req = new BerichtenOphalen();
    this.DataContext = req.getBerichten("lode_vl@hotmail.com");
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

This is where i try to get my list to use as datacontext for my app, there is never any data in it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is currently broken - you've got two variables called `berichten`, one of which is a *local* variable within the method, and one of which is an *instance* variable in the class.

You're returning the value of the local variable, but you're asynchronously populating the list referred to by the instance variable. That means your return value will always refer to an empty list, even after the asynchronous action has executed.

If you fix that bug, the list is *still* going to be empty when the method returns (because the data won't have been fetched yet) and there's nothing in `List<T>` to help the UI notice when the collection has been updated. You could potentially use an `ObservableCollection<>`, but you'd want to make sure that you only changed the collection on the UI thread.

If you're able to use C# 5, I would look into `async`/`await` to be honest - that will force your method to return a `Task<List<string>>` but it'll indicate the asynchrony much more clearly. Your calling method would then look something like:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    BerichtenOphalen req = new BerichtenOphalen();
    DataContext = await req.GetBerichtenAsync("lode_vl@hotmail.com");
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

You might want to consider moving the `Base.OnNavigatedTo(e)` method *before* the rest of the code though - or removing it entirely. Basically you need to think about what the original behaviour is, and whether you want that to occur immediately, or only after you've fetched the data.

Comment: The local variable is from when i trying out different things and was still left in there. Is there any code example out there that can help me out of this I find it really hard to find any good information on this subject (and i am pretty new to windows phone)

Comment: @LodeVlaeminck: Well which approach do you want to use? If you're going to use async/await (which is what I'd suggest) you should read up on that - there's a *lot* of information available about async/await; just search in MSDN.

Comment: honestly i dont even know what 'base.OnNavigatedTo(e);' does. Like i said total noob. I am using Visual 2010 so i dont think i can use the async/await.

Comment: There's no out-of-the-box support for async-await for WP7 in VS2010, but it can be done. Also, restsharp for WP7 (and WP8 too) doesn't come with async-await support (though it can be easily extended).
Because of all that extra work (and the fact you are a beginner) i would suggest to stick with the asynchronousy model provided by rest-sharp.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider applying MVVM to your project.
Let your class `BerichtenOphalen` be a ViewModel. The Page with OnNavigatedTo is the View, which should bind in xaml to BerichtenOphalen's public property of type `ObservableCollection<Bericht>`. Switch `public List<Bericht> getBerichten(string email)` to `public void LoadBerichten(string email)`. This method, called from OnNavigatedTo, will fill the Bericht-ObservableCollection asynchronously on the UI thread. It won't return anything, but the View will be notified when there's something to display.

You're gonna save yourself a lot of problems when you switch to MVVM way of thinking about fetching and presenting data.

The simplest modification to your View Code is setting the DataContext not to the return value of the method, but to the property of `BerichtenOphalen` and update this property in LoadBerichten as described above.

Comment: I'll look into that, I gues i have to use MVVMLight ?

Comment: not really. MVVM is a pattern, not a framework. It's how you organize your code. MVVMLight will make matters slightly easier, but above all you should read more about MVVM as it is very closely related to the technology you're using.